# JS styling 3 per line

Tags: javascript, php, api, styling, twitch

I'm trying to make this so there is 3 on a line then a break then 3 more then a break etc..

Any help?

Code so far http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/69/

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=dayz&limit=15&type=suggest&callback=?", function (e) {
    var t = "";
    $.each(e.streams, function (e, n) {
        t = t + "<div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'></h3><div class='content1'><center><img src='" + n.channel.logo + "' width='33' height='30'/><b> <a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.name + "'>" + n.channel.display_name + " - " + n.viewers + "</b></a></center></div></div><div class='panel-body'><div class='content3'><center><a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.display_name + "'><img src='" + n.preview.medium + "' width='400' height='222'/></a></center></div></div>"
    });
    $("#content").html(t)
})
```

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0xvX.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/K9BRg/)

**Create 3 different `content` divs instead of 1**

```
<div id="content1" class="panel panel-default"></div>
<div id="content2" class="panel panel-default"></div>
<div id="content3" class="panel panel-default"></div>
```

**Style these divs**

```
.panel.panel-default {
    width:430px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Distribute the results accordingly**

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=dayz&limit=15&type=suggest&callback=?", function (e) {
    var t = u = v = "";
    $.each(e.streams, function (e, n) {
        switch ((e + 1) % 3) {
            case 1:
                t = t + "<div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'></h3><div class='content1'><center><img src='" + n.channel.logo + "' width='33' height='30'/><b> <a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.name + "'>" + n.channel.display_name + " - " + n.viewers + "</b></a></center></div></div><div class='panel-body'><div class='content3'><center><a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.display_name + "'><img src='" + n.preview.medium + "' width='400' height='222'/></a></center></div></div>";
                break;
            case 2:
                u = u + "<div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'></h3><div class='content1'><center><img src='" + n.channel.logo + "' width='33' height='30'/><b> <a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.name + "'>" + n.channel.display_name + " - " + n.viewers + "</b></a></center></div></div><div class='panel-body'><div class='content3'><center><a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.display_name + "'><img src='" + n.preview.medium + "' width='400' height='222'/></a></center></div></div>";
                break;
            case 3:
            default:
                v = v + "<div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'></h3><div class='content1'><center><img src='" + n.channel.logo + "' width='33' height='30'/><b> <a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.name + "'>" + n.channel.display_name + " - " + n.viewers + "</b></a></center></div></div><div class='panel-body'><div class='content3'><center><a href='http://twitch.tv/" + n.channel.display_name + "'><img src='" + n.preview.medium + "' width='400' height='222'/></a></center></div></div>";
                break;
        }
    });
    $("#content1").html(t);
    $("#content2").html(u);
    $("#content3").html(v);
})
```